# initializing reference variable of class object with member initializer list?

Tags: c++, reference, initialization-list, ctor-initializer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523361/11862989 from this answer this question is came into picture. I feel small
thing is wrong in that answer, so I commented out there but no reply from him (guy (190K Reputation) who's answer I am referring) so I am asking here that small part.

#### 1.

**.h**

```
struct A
{
    private:
        int &i;
    public:
        A(int);
};
```

**.cpp**

```
A::A(int k1): i(k1)   
{
    std::cout<<&k1<<" "<<k1<<"\n";
    std::cout<<&i<<" "<<i<<"\n";
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    int x=99;
    std::cout<<&x<<" "<<x<<"\n";
    A a1(x);
}
```

**Output**

```
0x72fe0c 99
0x72fde8 99
0x72fde8 99
```

#### 2.

**.h**

```
struct A
{
    private:
        int &i;  // __change__
    public:
        A(int&);
};
```

**.cpp**

```
A::A(int &k1): i(k1)    // __change__
{
    std::cout<<&k1<<" "<<k1<<"\n";
    std::cout<<&i<<" "<<i<<"\n";
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    int x=99;
    std::cout<<&x<<" "<<x<<"\n";
    A a1(x);
}
```

**Output**

```
0x72fe0c 99
0x72fe0c 99
0x72fe0c 99
```

in **2nd** code as we are passing reference of `x` through main and it is collected by `k1`. and now we passing reference of `k1` to `i`. means now `i` is referring to `k1` and `k1` is referring to `x`. means indirectly `i` is referring to `x` am I right ?

in **1st** I think here value of variable `x` is passed through main and it is collected by variable `k1` and then reference of `k1` is passed to variable `i`. so in this case variable `i` is referring to variable `k1` but variable `k` is not referring to variable `x` am I right ?

that guy(190K Reputation) whose answer I referred at top he used 1st method to do this, I think he is wrong and __2nd__method is right for initializing reference variable of object in class. am I right ?

Comment: The second means **directly** that `i` is referring to `x`. The initialization is indirect, but `i` ends up being a reference to `x`. In the first, the argument `k1` goes away when the constructor returns. `i` refers to something that no longer exists, and the behavior is undefined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68289424/11862989 check this answer too. It will give little bit more insight on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, good catch. Alok's example in the answer you refer to is defective. Your example already shows it, and possible consequences of the undefined behavior of referring to stale references can be seen in this [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/G943Y6oed). I made A::i public and changed the main function to

```
int main()
{
  int x = 99;
  cout << &x << " " << x << "\n";

  A a1(x);
  cout << a1.i << " " << "\n";    
  cout << a1.i << " " << "\n";    // not 99 any more!
}
```

The output in the example is

```
0x7fff6983d4dc 99
0x7fff6983d4b4 99
0x7fff6983d4b4 99
99 
32767
```

The first output creates enough action on the stack to overwrite the address `&a1.i`, which back then contained the local `k1`.

A smart compiler could detect this and warn about it; and indeed, clang says `warning: binding reference member 'i' to stack allocated parameter 'k1' [-Wdangling-field]`. gcc 10.2 does not warn.

Comment: `&A::i` is a pointer-to-member. Its value is determined solely by the definition of `A`; it's always valid. The pointer you want is `&a1.i`, which is a pointer to the `int` that `a1.i` was initialized to point at.

Comment: @Pete thanks for, well, pointing this out.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica are you sure about `undefined behavior` ? I am asking because when we talk about __pointer and address__  not __reference__ okay. So let say ` int a; int *p=&a` and  assume `a` is gone out of scope then that case is `dangling ptr` right. I didn't know  such thing for __reference`.

Comment: @AbhishekMane Yes, of course. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Dangling_references. As you can see in my example the memory may be re-used; especially writing to it can change arbitrary data (e.g. return addresses) with unforeseeable consequences.