# Problem while initializing reference variable of class through Member initialization list

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, member-initialization

#### code

```
#include<iostream>
struct A
{
    private:
        
    public:
        int &p,q;
        A(int &k1,int k2):p(k1),q(k2)
        {
            
        }

};

int main()
{
    int x=2;
    A a1(x,3);

    std::cout<<&x<<"\n";
//  std::cout<<&k1<<"\n";    commented out this as it gives error
    std::cout<<&a1.p<<"\n";
    
}
```

#### Output

```
0x6ffe1c
0x6ffe1c
```

`p` is referring to `k1` and `k1` is referring to `x`.

`K1` is going to out of scope right so trying to access it gives error okay. But `a1.p` actually referring to `k1` so it is referring to memory which is not exist. so why accessing `a1.p` not gives error.

Comment: There is no `k1` symbol in the `main` function. Why should it be possible to use a non-existing symbol?

Comment: And `a1.p` is a reference to `x` in the `main` function. As is the constructors `k1` variable.

Comment: @DrewDormann I corrected it.

Comment: To make your life easier, replace the word reference with alias, because that is what essentially it is.  In the constructor, `k1` is an alias for `x`, which means `p` is also an alias for `x`.

Comment: @DrewDormann What dangling reference?

Comment: @NathanOliver But it's through `k1` right ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane `k1` doesn't exist.  It's an alias for `x`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for answering but your 2nd comment is not  understandable

Comment: @NathanOliver Got it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you misunderstand how references work.

Once you have initialized a reference, you can never access the reference variable itself again. All use of the reference variable will be redirected to the variable being referenced instead.

So in the `A` constructor, the variable `k1` can never be used, all use of it will be of the `x` variable in the `main` function. There can't be a dangling reference with the code as currently shown at the time of writing this answer.

In short: You can't create a reference of a reference.

---

***However*** if you modified the `A` constructor to take the first argument *by value* instead of by reference:

```
A(int k1, int k2) : p(k1), q(k2) {}
```

Then *that* would lead to a dangling reference of the `k1` variable.

Comment: `int x=2; `  `int &k1=x; ` ` int &p=k1` so I am trying to make reference of `k1` but actually it creating reference of x here right ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane That's correct. It's not possible to create a reference to `k1` since it's in turn a reference.